# An instance when you can eliminate propositional double negation in coq

Tags: programming-languages, logic, coq

Suppose `st: string -> nat` and `X` stands for the string `'X'`.

Given the hypothesis `not(st X <> 0)`, I can successfully derive

```
assert (st X = 0). { omega. }
```

But in Coq's constructive logic, a proposition of the form `(P -> False) -> False` does not in general imply `P`.

I imagine the fact that `st` is a function enables one to prove the above theorem.
If this is the case, then how does the `omega` tactic use this fact in the proof?

Though I am aware that `omega` is an implementation of a certain decision procedure for a weak form of arithmetic, I know almost nothing about how it works.

I am just looking for a general explanation. There's no need for many details.

Comment: Equality is decidable for naturals.